# How can I find the chipset of my Arduino board?

Tags: mac-address, arduino, lsusb

I've recently purchased an Arduino Pro Micro, which I am using as a BadUSB for experimental purposes. On Hak5, they spoofed the MAC Address of a USB Rubber Ducky to look like an Apple device [(Hak5 Video)](https://youtu.be/qGPGOoJn54E?t=16m). That is what I'm trying to do. Should I use `lsusb`? How would I find the chipset so I can spoof/change the device's MAC Address?